# how to run chisq.test in loops using apply

Tags: r, loops, matrix, apply, chi-squared

I am a newbie of R.
Due to the need of my project, I need to do Chisq test for hundred thousand entries.

I learned by myself for a few days and write some code for runing chisq.test in loops.
codes:

```
the.data = read.table ("test_chisq_allelefrq.txt", header=T, sep="\t",row.names=1)
p=c()
ID=c()
for (i in 1:nrow(the.data)) {
data.row = the.data [i,]
data.matrix = matrix ( c(data.row$cohort_1_AA, data.row$cohort_1_AB,       data.row$cohort_1_BB, data.row$cohort_2_AA, data.row$cohort_2_AB, data.row$cohort_2_BB,data.row$cohort_3_AA,data.row$cohort_3_AB,data.row$cohort_3_BB), byrow=T, nrow=3)
chisq = chisq.test(data.matrix)
pvalue=chisq$p.value
p=c(p, pvalue)
No=row.names(the.data)[i]
ID=c(rsid, SNP )
}
results=data.frame(ID,p)
write.table (results,  file = "chisq-test_output.txt", append=F, quote = F, sep = "\t ",eol = "\n", na = "NA", dec = ".", row.names = F, col.names = T)
```

this code might have several problems. but it works.

However, it runs very slow.

I try to improve it by using "apply"

I plan to use apply twice instead of using "for"

```
datarow= apply (the.data,1,  matrix(the.data, byrow=T, nrow=3))
result=apply(datarow,1,chisq.test)
```

However, there is error saying matrix is not a function. zsd the chisq.test output is a list, I cannot use write.table to output the data.

the.data is like this.

```
SN0001 and 9 numbers
           cohort_1_AA cohort_1_AB cohort_1_BB cohort_2_AA cohort_2_AB cohort_2_BB cohort_3_AA cohort_3_AB cohort_3_BB
SN0001     197         964        1088       877      858      168     351    435      20
....
....
```

I have been trying for days and nights. 
Hope someone can help me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: `apply` isn't a magic bullet.  The only overhead that `for` gives you is extending the result vector, but that's minor compared to the test and you can fix that by pre-allocating.  `apply` should be used when it makes the expression easier to read, not for speed (because it isn't faster).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use apply group of functions it is easy first to define our own function and then apply it.
Lets do that.

```
    ##first define the function to apply
    Chsq <- function(x){
   ## input is a row of your data
   ## creating a table from each row
         x <- matrix(x,byrow =TRUE,nrow=3)
    ### this will return the p value
      return(chisq.test(x)$p.value)
    }
## Now apply this function
data = read.table ("test_chisq_allelefrq.txt", header=T, sep="\t",row.names=1)
## by using as.vector convert the output into a vector
P_Values <- as.vector(apply(data,1,Chsq))
result <- cbind(rownames(data),P_Values)
write.table (results,  file = "chisq-test_output.txt", append=F, quote = F, sep = "\t ",eol = "\n", na = "NA", dec = ".", row.names = F, col.names = T)
```

Try this code hopefully it works !! :) Accept the answer as correct if it works for you. thanks

Comment: thank you,koudy. the code works. I just realized that apply didnot improve the speed. It basically equals to "for". I can make it work using "for"...But my purpose is to make it faster as there are hundred thousand chisq test. do you have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

One `for` loop implies one `apply`, not two.

Something like this:

```
result=apply(the.data, 1, function(data.row) {
   ## Your code using data.row
})
```

If the result is more readable than the `for` loop, go with it.  Otherwise stick with what you have.  `apply` won't be noticeably different in speed (faster or slower).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. then how can I improve the speed?

Comment: I just searched. people mentioned about package plyr. will plyr help ?

Comment: @user3766160 probably not. Learn how to profile code and search for bottlenecks. You can start here: http://site.iugaza.edu.ps/biqelan/files/2010/09/Braun-W.J.-Murdoch-D.J.-A-First-Course-in-Statistical-Programming-with-R-CUP-2007ISBN-0521872650175s.pdf